# JQL to retrive specific columns for a cetain label

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jql, python-jira

I have limited experience with Jira and Jira query language.

This is regarding JIRA Query language. I have a set of 124 rows (issues) in Jira that are under a certain 'Label' say 'myLabel'.

I need to extract columns col1, col2 and col5 for all of the above 124 rows where the Label field is 'myLabel'.

Once I have the above result I need to export it to an excel sheet. Is there a JIRA query that I can fire to do this ?

Or Is there some other way that this can be done, like maybe exporting all of the 124 rows with all the n columns to a SQL table and then doing an SQL query on top of it to retrieve the results that is needed ?

Also there is something python-jira. Can that be of some help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to get issues by label via an http GET:

http://yourserver.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=labels%20%3D%20SearchString

Replace "SearchString" with the label you want to search for.
This will return you a JSON object with a (JSON) array of issues.

I am more familiar with the Java API than the python one, but I imagine it should be pretty easy to to take the JSON array and put it into an excel sheet (or into a CSV file that excel will play nicely with).

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this stuff what you want to do is with Excel directly.
0. create the filter in JIRA
1. create a VBA for Excel script which will Open the Exported to Excel filter from JIRA. In order to do that you have to copy the link from JIRA, -> export -> Excel current fields. 
2. Most probably you will have to login first to JIRA from EXCEL VBA, so I recommend you to do this by logging in with REST requests from excel.
3. Copy all the information from the exported JIRA query to your other worksheet
4. After copying you can then process as you wish easily with VBA the list of tickets.

I know this is not the straight forward way of doing this stuff, but I hope it helped you a little to go further into your searches.